# python regex - split a string at '|' except inside any brackets

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

I'm relatively new to python regex. I want to split a string at '|' other than at braces.

Example :

```
Str = " a | ( b | c ) | d "
```

I want the following result

```
Result = ["a","( b | c )","d"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try splitting a string by `'|'` character
escaping anything in parentheses

```
Str = " a | ( b | c ) | d "
a=re.split(r'\|\s*(?![^()]*\))',Str)
print(a)
[' a ', '( b | c ) ', 'd ']
```

Comment: how do i handle nested braces?